# angular2 rc6 custom global pipes; PLATFORM_PIPES

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I am using angular with version 2.0.0-rc.6 in older versions there was a possibility to create a global pipe and register it like is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044068/is-it-possible-to-override-the-built-in-angular-2-pipes-so-they-can-be-used-glob) and in many other locations online.

I am trying to do something similar in my app but there is a problem I encountered,
I can't import PLATFORM_PIPES from angular/core and I also read that it is deprecated on the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and other places on line.

I found this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484113/angular-2-global-pipes-without-platform-pipes) on the matter, but it did not help me since I am using @NgModule and I can't seem to find a way to put the pipe in it in any way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Demo of Default-Pipe & Custom-Pipe: 

https://plnkr.co/edit/BmZrCbl0czJwnPMf0x0V?p=preview**

---

**Default pipe**

*You don't need to do anything for this.*

*Since **PLATFORM_PIPES** has been deprecated, in **RC6**, **default pipes** are available **by default**.*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `  {{mydate | date:"MM/dd/yy"}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
   mydate = Date.now();
}
```

---

**Custom pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'awesome' })

export class AwesomePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(phrase: string) {
    return phrase ? 'Awesome ' + phrase : '';
  }
}
```

I want to use it in AppComponent

```
 @NgModule({
   imports:      [ BroswerModule, FormsModule ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent, AwesomePipe ],  //<----added here
   exports:      [ AppComponent],
   providers:    [ ]
  })
```

**.html**

```
 {{ your data/value | awesome }}
```

Comment: I am talking about a custom global type and not a default one.

Comment: That is my question, how to register it?

Comment: Ok wonderful thank you very much this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: I also updated my plunker link with both types of pipes.